# Ошибка скрипта ffmpeg youtube -dl

Tags: bash, cmd

имеется скрипт Bash:

```
ffmpeg -i `youtube-dl https://www.twitch.tv/zero` -vf fps=fps=60, scale=1920x1080 -c:v libx264 -b:v 500k -preset superfast -c:a copy -f segment -segment_time 60 test.mp4
```

Возникает ошибка с запуском:

```
`youtube-dl: No such file or directory
```

Пробовал  `'youtube-dl https://www.twitch.tv/zero'`, та же ошибка

Пробовал  `"youtube-dl https://www.twitch.tv/zero"`, ошибка:`youtube-dl https://www.twitch.tv/zero: Invalid argument`

Что я делаю не так?

Comment: программы bash и cmd не имеют никакого отношения к программе ffmpeg. смотрите справку к этой программе. именно к той сборке, которую вам надо выполнить.

Comment: @alexanderbarakin у меня этот скрипт не запускается на cmd

Comment: в вашей системе *ffmpeg* — это скрипт? смотрите внутрь него, в каком виде он хочет принимать опции. если же это всё-таки программа, то смотрите (про это же самое — формат опций) справку к этой программе. именно к той сборке, к которой вы обращаетесь (то ли «нативной досовской», то ли через какую-нибудь полу-эмуляция типа cygwin и т.п.)

Answer (score 0):

Установите `youtube-dl`. У вас его просто нет.

Comment: вы ошибаетесь, youtube-dl https://www.twitch.tv/zero он выполняет нормально